# Rendering an expression tree in Java

Tags: java, draw

I had previously written code that would take a mathematical expression and turn it into a parse tree, I am now trying to visually display the tree that has been created by drawing on a JPanel. The expression is input into the console by the user, it outputs the postfix and I want to also display the tree. However when I run my current program the tree is not rendered on the JPanel. I don't get any errors from the compiler so I'm unsure what the issue is.

```
public class TreeView extends JPanel {
//Class for drawing the Tree onto a panel
private int radius = 20;
private int levelGap = 50;
ExpTree t;

public TreeView(ExpTree t) {
    this.t = t;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);

    if (t.getRoot() != null) {
        displayTree(g, t.getRoot(), getWidth() / 2, 30, getWidth() / 4);
    }
}

private void displayTree(Graphics g, ExpTree t, int x, int y, int gap) {
    g.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    g.drawString(t.getLeafVal() + "", x - 6, y + 4);

    if (t.getlChild() != null) {
        connectCircles(g, x - gap, y + levelGap, x, y);
        displayTree(g, t.lChild, x - gap, y + levelGap, gap /2);
    }

    if (t.getrChild() != null) {
        connectCircles(g, x + gap, y + levelGap, x, y);
        displayTree(g, t.rChild, x + gap, y + levelGap, gap /2);
    }
}

private void connectCircles(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    double d = Math.sqrt(levelGap * levelGap + (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1));
    int x11 = (int)(x1 - radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
    int y11 = (int)(y1 - radius * (y1 - y2) / d);
    int x21 = (int)(x2 + radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
    int y21 = (int)(y2 + radius * (y1 - y2) / d);
    g.drawLine(x11, y11, x21, y21);
  }
}

public class Test extends JFrame {

public Test() {
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    add(jp);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Test test = new Test();

    //create parse trees from input in console
    boolean done = false;
    boolean valid = false;
    Parser p = new Parser();
    ExpTree myTree;
    System.out.println("Enter an expression to convert into postfix notation");
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter an expression: ");
        try {
            myTree = p.parseLine();
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Expression: Ensure it ends with a semicolon");
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(myTree.toPostfix(myTree));
        TreeView view = new TreeView(myTree);
        test.add(view);
        view.repaint();

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another expression? (y/n)");
        do {
            String s = p.getLine();
            switch (s) {
                case "y" : valid = true;
                    done = false;
                    continue;
                case "n" : valid = true;
                    done = true;
                    continue;
                default: valid = false;
                    done = false;
                    System.out.println("Invalid input: Must be y or n");
            }
        } while (!valid);
    } while (!done);
  }
}


//Setup of the tree incase it's useful
public class ExpTree {
    //Tree object that is created when an expression is parsed
    private int type;
    private Object leafVal;
    public ExpTree lChild, rChild;
    public static final int NUM = 0, VAL = 1, OP = 2;
    private StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    public ExpTree(int type, Object leafVal, ExpTree l, ExpTree r) {
        this.type = type;
        this.leafVal = leafVal;
        this.lChild = l;
        this.rChild = r;
    }
   //return the forth expression, a postfix expression
public String toPostfix(ExpTree t) {
    if (t != null) {
        toPostfix(t.lChild);
        toPostfix(t.rChild);
        sb.append(t.leafVal);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public ExpTree getRoot() {
    return this;
}

public Object getLeafVal() {
    return leafVal;
}

public ExpTree getlChild() {
    return lChild;
}

public ExpTree getrChild() {
    return rChild;
}
}

class ParseException extends RuntimeException
{ public ParseException(String s)
{ super("Invalid expression: "+s);
}
}

public class Parser
{ private Lexer lex;

  public Parser()
  { lex = new Lexer();
  }

  public ExpTree parseLine()
  { lex.init();
    lex.getToken();
    ExpTree result = parseExp(true);
    if (lex.token==Lexer.where)
    { lex.getToken();
      ExpTree defs = parseDefList();
      result = makeWhereTree(result, defs);
    }
    if (lex.token!=Lexer.semico)
    { throw new ParseException("semicolon expected");
    }
    return result;
  }

  public String getLine()
  { return lex.getLine();
  }

  private ExpTree parseExp(boolean idsAllowed)
  { ExpTree result = parseTerm(idsAllowed);
    { while (lex.token==Lexer.plus || lex.token==Lexer.minus)
    { int op = lex.token;
      lex.getToken();
      if (op==Lexer.plus)
        result = makePlusTree(result, parseTerm(idsAllowed));
      else
        result = makeMinusTree(result, parseTerm(idsAllowed));
    }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private ExpTree parseTerm(boolean idsAllowed)
  { ExpTree result = parseOpd(idsAllowed);
    { while (lex.token==Lexer.times || lex.token==Lexer.div || lex.token==Lexer.mod)
    { int op = lex.token;
      lex.getToken();
      if (op==Lexer.times)
        result = makeTimesTree(result, parseOpd(idsAllowed));
      else if (op==Lexer.mod)
        result = makeModTree(result, parseOpd(idsAllowed));
      else
        result = makeDivideTree(result, parseOpd(idsAllowed));
    }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private ExpTree parseOpd(boolean idsAllowed)
  { ExpTree result;
    switch(lex.token)
    { case Lexer.num:
      result = makeNumberLeaf(lex.numval);
      lex.getToken();
      return result;
      case Lexer.id:
        if (!idsAllowed)
          throw new ParseException("identifier not allowed in identifier defintion");
        result = makeIdLeaf(lex.idval);
        lex.getToken();
        return result;
      case Lexer.lp:
        lex.getToken();
        result = parseExp(idsAllowed);
        if (lex.token!=Lexer.rp)
          throw new ParseException("right parenthesis expected");
        lex.getToken();
        return result;
      default:
        throw new ParseException("invalid operand");
    }
  }

  private ExpTree parseDefList()
  { ExpTree result = parseDef();
    while (lex.token==Lexer.and)
    { lex.getToken();
      result = makeAndTree(result, parseDef());
    }
    return result;
  }

  private ExpTree parseDef()
  { if (lex.token!=Lexer.id)
    throw new ParseException("definition must start with identifier");
    char id = lex.idval;
    if (Character.isUpperCase(id))
      throw new ParseException("upper-case identifiers cannot be used in defintion list");
    lex.getToken();
    if (lex.token!=Lexer.eq)
      throw new ParseException("'=' expected");
    lex.getToken();
    return makeDefTree(id, parseExp(false));
  }

  // the next seven methods need to be modified for part 3 of the assignment
  static ExpTree makeNumberLeaf(int n)
  { return new ExpTree(ExpTree.NUM, n, null, null);
    // this method should return a new number leaf with value n created using your constructor
    // if you've used the abstract class approach you will probably need something like
    // return new NumLeaf(n);
    // if you've used an ExpTree class that stores the node kind you will probably need something like
    // return new ExpTree(ExpTree.numNode, n , null, null);
  }

  static ExpTree makeIdLeaf(char c)
  { return new ExpTree(ExpTree.VAL, c, null, null);
    // this method should return a new id leaf with value c
  }

  static ExpTree makePlusTree(ExpTree l, ExpTree r)
  { return new ExpTree(ExpTree.OP, '+', l, r);
    // this method should return a new plus node with children l and r created using your constructor
    // if you've used the abstract class approach you will probably need something like
    // return new OpNode('+', l, r);
    // or
    // return new PlusNode(l, r);
    // if you've used an ExpTree class that stores the node kind you will probably need something like
    // return new ExpTree(ExpTree.opMode, '+', l, r);
  }

  static ExpTree makeMinusTree(ExpTree l, ExpTree r)
  { return new ExpTree(ExpTree.OP, '-', l, r);
    // this method should return a new minus node with children l and r
  }

  static ExpTree makeTimesTree(ExpTree l, ExpTree r)
  { return new ExpTree(ExpTree.OP, '*', l, r);
    // this method should return a new times node with children l and r
  }

  static ExpTree makeDivideTree(ExpTree l, ExpTree r)
  { return new ExpTree(ExpTree.OP, '/', l, r);
    // this method should return a new divide node with children l and r
  }

  static ExpTree makeModTree(ExpTree l, ExpTree r)
  { return new ExpTree(ExpTree.OP, '%', l, r);
    // this method should return a new mod (%) node with children l and r
  }

  // the next three methods need to be modified for part 6 of the assignment - do not modify them if you have not attempted part 6

  static ExpTree makeWhereTree(ExpTree l, ExpTree r)
  { // remove the following line if you modify this method; leave it here if you do not attempt part 6
    System.out.println("Part 6 not attempted");
    return null;
    // this method should return a new 'where' node with children l and r
  }

  static ExpTree makeAndTree(ExpTree l, ExpTree r)
  { return null;
    // this method should return a new 'and' node with children l and r
  }

  static ExpTree makeDefTree(char c, ExpTree t)
  { return null;
    // this method should return a new definition node with identifier c and child t
    // if your definition nodes have 2 children you should put a new id leaf in the left child and use t as the right child
  }
}

class Lexer
{ static final int err = 0, num = 1, id = 2, plus = 3, minus = 4, times = 5, div = 6, mod = 7,
        lp = 8, rp = 9, semico = 10, where = 11, and = 12, eq = 13;
  int token;
  char idval;
  int numval;
  private String line = "";
  private BufferedReader buf;

  Lexer()
  { buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  }

  void init()
  { do
    try
    { line = buf.readLine().trim();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { System.out.println("Error in input");
      System.exit(1);
    }
  while (line.length()==0);
  }

  String getLine()
  { init();
    return(line);
  }

  void getToken()
  { if (line.length()==0)
    token = err;
  else switch (line.charAt(0))
    { case '+':
      token = plus;
      line = line.substring(1).trim();
      break;
      case '-':
        token = minus;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      case '*':
        token = times;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      case '/':
        token = div;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      case '%':
        token = mod;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      case '(':
        token = lp;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      case ')':
        token = rp;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      case ';':
        token = semico;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      case '=':
        token = eq;
        line = line.substring(1).trim();
        break;
      default:
        if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(0)))
        { token = num;
          numval = line.charAt(0) - '0';
          int i = 1;
          while (i<line.length()&&Character.isDigit(line.charAt(i)))
          { numval = numval*10+line.charAt(i)-'0';
            i++;
          }
          line = line.substring(i).trim();
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(0)))
        { char c = line.charAt(0);
          if (c=='w' && line.length()>=5 && line.charAt(1)=='h' && line.charAt(2)=='e' && line.charAt(3)=='r' &&
                  line.charAt(4)=='e')
          { token = where;
            line = line.substring(5).trim();
          }
          else if (c=='a' && line.length()>=3 && line.charAt(1)=='n' && line.charAt(2)=='d')
          { token = and;
            line = line.substring(3).trim();
          }
          else if (line.length()>1 && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(1)))
          { token = err;
          }
          else
          { token = id;
            idval = c;
            line = line.substring(1).trim();
          }
        }
        else
          token = err;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Some methods missing in your ExpTree to try and replicate your problem

Comment: The `Test` JFrame has a `BorderLayout`, but you're not telling the components where they should be put in the BorderLayout. Only the one in the CENTER will use all the remaining space - the others will be set based on their minimum size, which you don't set, so they won't get any space.

Comment: @Alfabravo my copy/paste must've cut off, all code should be there now

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Tried adding the TreeView JPanel to CENTER but there's still nothing being drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, long ago, that I made swing stuff.

In Test.main, if I replace

```
        System.out.println(myTree.toPostfix(myTree));
        TreeView view = new TreeView(myTree);
        test.add(view);
        view.repaint();
```

with:

```
        System.out.println (myTree.toPostfix(myTree));
        TreeView view = new TreeView(myTree);
        test.add (view);
        // view.repaint();
        test.invalidate ();
```

I get a somehow splittet graph - probably a step to begin with.

[image]

```
4+2*3-9*4+2*3-9;
4 2 3 * + 9 4 * - 2 3 * + 9 -
```

But only after going to fullsize. Resizing demolates the graphic and the program hangs.

2 additional improvements, one critical, one user friendlyness:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

should be added to the CTor

```
public Test() {
```

before setVisible, so you don't have to stop the Program with Ctrl-C. That was the critical one.

The second is in the lexer. If you test the input after trimming on line.endsWith (";"), you may add the semicolon silently yourself, instead of telling the user, what and how to do it.
Even better: Add a JTextField at BorderLayout (NORTH) or SOUTH, for the formula, so that the user may update it. For testing purpose it would be nice to prefill it.

## Update

I meanwhile had fun, improving it, which might be mostly a question of taste and priorities, but maybe you're interested. And one step is most probably better, than the invalidate-command above.

[image]

here are the needed imports:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
```

Here the TestTreeView (I have way to much classes called 'Test'):

```
public class TestTreeView extends JFrame {

    JTextField jtf = new JTextField (30);
    JButton jb = new JButton ("go!");

    public TestTreeView () {
        setSize (900, 600); // a
        Container cp = getContentPane (); // b
        JPanel jp = new JPanel ();
        jp.setLayout (new BorderLayout());
        cp.add (jp);
        jp.setBorder (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder ()); // c
        JPanel tp = new JPanel ();
        tp.setLayout (new FlowLayout ());
        tp.add (jtf);
        jtf.setText ("1+2*3/4%5");
        jtf.setFont ((jtf.getFont()).deriveFont (24.0f)); // I like big fonts, maybe need stronger glasses :) 
        tp.add (jb);
        jp.add (tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        actions (jp); // see below
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible (true);
    }

    public void actions (JPanel jp) {
        jb.addActionListener (ae -> {
            String s = jtf.getText ();
            System.out.println (s);
            if (s.length () > 1) {
                //create parse trees from input in JTextField
                Parser p = new Parser (s); // redefined, see below 
                ExpTree myTree;

                try {
                    myTree = p.parseLine ();
                    System.out.println (myTree.toPostfix(myTree));

                    TreeView view = new TreeView (myTree);
                    jp.add (view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    // view.repaint();
                    // jp.invalidate ();
                    jp.revalidate (); // c
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    System.out.println ("Invalid Expression: Ensure it ends with a semicolon");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TestTreeView test = new TestTreeView ();
    }
}
```

Remarks:

- a) I need more space, hence 900x600
- b) At least to Java-1.5, you shouldn't add to the main Frame, but to the contentPane. Maybe it changed with 1.6, 1.7 or 1.8
- c) revalidate is the way to go. Paints right up front, not just after first resize. This should apply, even if you don't like to use JTextField and button.

Parser found a new CTor, which expects a String, we pass from the JTextField:

```
class Parser
{
    private Lexer lex;

    public Parser()
    {
        lex = new Lexer();
    }

    public Parser (String s)
    {
        lex = new Lexer (s);
    }
```

and Lexer found a new CTor, which expects a String, which is passed from the Parser:

```
class Lexer
void init()
{
    do
        try
        {
            line = buf.readLine ().trim ();
            if (! line.endsWith (";"))
                line = String.format ("%s;", line);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in input");
            System.exit (1);
        }
    while (line.length () == 0);
}

{
    // ...  
    Lexer ()
    {
        buf = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    Lexer (String s)
    {
        buf = new BufferedReader (new StringReader (s));
    }
```

// plus the automatic semicolon healing:

```
    void init()
    {
        do
            try
            {
                line = buf.readLine ().trim ();
                if (! line.endsWith (";"))
                    line = String.format ("%s;", line);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error in input");
                System.exit (1);
            }
        while (line.length () == 0);
    }
```

Last famous words. In the net, there are a lot tutorials, how to detach the work of actions like in the ActionListener from the main event loop. You should consider working through such material. This code here is not state of the art. :)

Comment: Thanks! That's helped a lot at least to get started, hopefully I can fix the drawing of the lines.

Comment: So the reason it's not adding a line to the left child of any node is because the y values give a negative which obviously gives an error when trying to do the sqrt. Switching them around simply gives a line at the opposite angle.

Edit: I misread I needed to do (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) instead of (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1), it's now drawing both lines correctly.